# Toggle in jquery div sliding out

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide, slidetoggle

I have made  Jquery div sliding out inside a Slideshow. I have used this [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide) to build it up.

If you look up [here](http://tommywebdesigner.com/Albert/index.html) my case you can find the Jquery div sliding out inside the slideshow, if you click on the arrow, the dive comes out but i can not give the function that once the slide come out, it can get closed clicking on the *arrow back*.

Probably there was an easier and better way to do that, this is the code i am using for that.

How can i make my arrow-back working to close the div sliding out? If you think that there is a better way to achieve that, let me know.

Hope the explanation is clear

Thanks for your help

```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
          $(".click").click(function ()
          {
             $(".slideout").toggle("slide", {}, 100);
             $('.click').hide();
             $('.back').toggle();
          });
     });
</script>
```

My CSS Code:

```
    .slideout { display: none; margin: 0px; width: 300px; height: 450px; background: url("img/rejilla.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; position: absolute; z-index: 101; top:15px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 16px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius-topleft: 16px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px; border-top-left-radius: 16px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; opacity: 0.5; }
    .click { z-index: 102; left:-15px; position: absolute; top: 10px; z-index:102; }
    .back {float: right; position: absolute; z-index: 102; left: 285px; top: 15px; display: none;}
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="slideshow">
        <div id="example">
            <img src="img/arrow.png" class="click" alt="arrow" width="50" height="100" /><div class="slideout">bla bla bla</div><img src="img/arrow-prev.png" class="back" alt="arrow" width="50" height="100" /> 
                <div id="slides">
                    <div class="slides_container">
                        <a href="" title="Slide 1" target="_blank"><img class="slide" src="img/slide-1.jpg" alt="slide-1" width="1020" height="450" /></a>
                        <a href="" title="Slide 2" target="_blank"><img class="slide" src="img/slide-2.jpg" alt="slide-2" width="1020" height="450" /></a>
                        <a href="" title="Slide 3" target="_blank"><img class="slide" src="img/slide-3.jpg" alt="slide-3" width="1020" height="450" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your html code too...sp that it will be easy to figure out wat is wrong

Comment: done @bipen, have a look. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

HTML Code

```
<img id="myImg" class="click" width="50" height="100" alt="arrow" src="img/arrow.png">
```

Javascript

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      $("#myImg").click(function ()
      {
         $(".slideout").toggle("slide", {}, 100);
         if($(this).hasClass('click')){
            $(this).removeClass('click');
            $(this).addClass('back');
         }else{
            $(this).removeClass('back');
            $(this).addClass('click');
         }
      });
 });
</script>
```

I have not checked the code , so this is just rough idea

Comment: I coded it with fade in/Out (supported by IE) and i got  it working,          $(".click").click(function () {
        $(".slideout").fadeIn("slow");
        $('.click').hide();
        $('.back').toggle();
        });

      
     $(".back").click(function () {
      $(".slideout").fadeOut("slow");
      $('.click').toggle();
      $('.back').hide();
     });
 what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

how about using something like this:

```
$(".click").click(function() {
    margin = +$('.slideout').css('margin-left').replace('px', '');
    if (margin < 0)
    {
        $('.slideout').animate({marginLeft: "0px"}, 500 );
        $('.click').text('<');
    } else {
        $('.slideout').animate({marginLeft: "-200px"}, 500 );
        $('.click').text('>');
    }        
});​
```

obviously you can fancy it up a bit (not using < and > to denote direction would be start) but slideout works, [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qZ6q7/2/) although it's not using your html

EDIT - Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qZ6q7/3/) using a very slightly altered version of your html. I have reduced the width of the slides and rearranged some of the slideout stuff (with the click image etc) to make it a little easier to understand.

Let me know if that's working as you wanted now, it should be very easy to implement.

Comment: Do you need help getting this to work with your markup, or is the code above enough for you?

Comment: Hi pete!..i am trying to figure out with my markup, if you can give me help, it's so appreciate, rajesh kakawat code is clear, but it does not work.